# Dynamic Jquery Code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a way to write dynamic codes in Jquery.

Please take a look at these codes below and here is a [live sample](http://jsfiddle.net/kG2AZ/187/)

Everything works as expected, but Jquery codes repeats and kind of long!
Is there any way to turn this Jquery to dymamic one.

Thanks!

```
JS

$("#link1").click(function(){
    $("#table-filters>ul>li.red").removeClass("red");
  $(".link1").addClass('red');
});
$("#link2").click(function(){
    $("#table-filters>ul>li.red").removeClass("red");
  $(".link2").addClass('red');
});
$("#link3").click(function(){
    $("#table-filters>ul>li.red").removeClass("red");
  $(".link3").addClass('red');
});
$("#link4").click(function(){
    $("#table-filters>ul>li.red").removeClass("red");
  $(".link4").addClass('red');
});
$("#link5").click(function(){
    $("#table-filters>ul>li.red").removeClass("red");
  $(".link5").addClass('red');
});

HTML

<div id="table-filters">
    <ul>
        <li class="link1">link 1</li>
        <li class="link2">link 2</li>
        <li class="link3">link 3</li>
        <li class="link4">link 4</li>
        <li class="link5">link 5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<p>
<button id="link1">link1 Button</button>
<button id="link2">link2 Button</button>
<button id="link3">link3 Button</button>
<button id="link4">link4 Button</button>
<button id="link5">link5 Button</button>
</p>

CSS

.red {
  color: red;
}
li {
  float:left;
  margin-right: 10px
}
p {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
button {
  corsor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest the following approach:

```
// select all elements with an 'id' attribute whose value
// begins with 'link':
$('button[id^=link]')

  // bind the anonymous function of the on() method as
  // as the event-handler for the 'click' event:
  .on('click', function() {

    // finding the <li> elements with a class equal to the
    // id of the clicked <button> element, contained within
    // the #table-filters element:
    $('#table-filters li.' + this.id)

      // add the 'red' class to that element:
      .addClass('red')

      // select the siblings of that <li> element:
      .siblings()

      // remove the 'red' class from those sibling <li> elements:
      .removeClass('red');
});
```

```js
$('button[id^=link]').on('click', function() {
  $('#table-filters li.' + this.id).addClass('red').siblings().removeClass('red');
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}

li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

p {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table-filters">
  <ul>
    <li class="link1">link 1</li>
    <li class="link2">link 2</li>
    <li class="link3">link 3</li>
    <li class="link4">link 4</li>
    <li class="link5">link 5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<p>
  <button id="link1">link1 Button</button>
  <button id="link2">link2 Button</button>
  <button id="link3">link3 Button</button>
  <button id="link4">link4 Button</button>
  <button id="link5">link5 Button</button>
</p>
```

This is also possible using plain JavaScript:

```
// defining a function to handle the 'highlight' functionality:
function highlight() {

  // using Array.from() to convert the nodeList returned from
  // document.querySelectorAll() into an Array:
  Array.from(

    // finding all the <li> elements within the
    // #table-filters element:
    document.querySelectorAll('#table-filters li')

  // iterating over that Array of nodes using
  // Array.prototype.forEach():
  ).forEach(

    // 'link' is a reference to the current node of the Array
    // of Nodes over which we're iterating;here we access the
    // Element.classList property, and use a ternary operator
    // to determine whether we should use the 'add()' or
    // 'remove()' method:
    link => link.classList[

      // if the classList of the current node ('link') contains
      // a class equal to the id attribute of the clicked (this)
      // <button> we return the 'add' function-name, otherwise
      // we return the 'remove' function-name (using the square-
      // bracket syntax to access properties of the current
      // Object):
      link.classList.contains(this.id) ? 'add' : 'remove'

    // we pass the 'red' string as an argument:
    ]('red')
  )

}

// using Array.from() to convert the nodeList returned by
// document.querySelectorAll() into an Array:
Array.from(

  // here we find all <button> elements with an 'id' attribute
  // whose attribute-value starts with 'link':
  document.querySelectorAll('button[id^=link]')

// iterating over the Array of nodes:
).forEach(

  // 'button' is a reference to the current node of the
  // Array of nodes over which we're iterating; here
  // we use the EventTarget.addEventListener() function
  // to bind the named function ('highlight') as the event-
  // handler for the 'click' event:
  button => button.addEventListener('click', highlight)
);
```

```js
function highlight() {
  Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll('#table-filters li')
  ).forEach(
    link => link.classList[link.classList.contains(this.id) ? 'add' : 'remove']('red')
  )

}

Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll('button[id^=link]')
).forEach(
  button => button.addEventListener('click', highlight)
);
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}

li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

p {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="table-filters">
  <ul>
    <li class="link1">link 1</li>
    <li class="link2">link 2</li>
    <li class="link3">link 3</li>
    <li class="link4">link 4</li>
    <li class="link5">link 5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<p>
  <button id="link1">link1 Button</button>
  <button id="link2">link2 Button</button>
  <button id="link3">link3 Button</button>
  <button id="link4">link4 Button</button>
  <button id="link5">link5 Button</button>
</p>
```

References:

- CSS:

  - [Attribute selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors).
- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [Arrow function syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
  - [`Element.classList` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
- jQuery:

  - [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
  - [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).
  - [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

Comment: Thank Commercial Suicide, David Thomas, Bhuwan Bhatt and john Smith so much!  Well, there are many ways to get it works.  You are all amazing!  If I could accept every answer, I would do so!

Answer (score 1):

```
JS

// a bit more dynamic using a class to capture the click


$(".link").click(function(){
    $("#table-filters>ul>li.red").removeClass("red");
  $("."+$(this).attr("id")).addClass('red');
});

HTML

<div id="table-filters">
    <ul>
        <li class="link1">link 1</li>
        <li class="link2">link 2</li>
        <li class="link3">link 3</li>
        <li class="link4">link 4</li>
        <li class="link5">link 5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<p>
<button class="link" id="link1">link1 Button</button>
<button class="link" id="link2">link2 Button</button>
<button class="link" id="link3">link3 Button</button>
<button class="link" id="link4">link4 Button</button>
<button class="link" id="link5">link5 Button</button>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your ***button's ids*** and ***link's classes*** name are same, so you can use them to ***add*** or ***remove*** the `red` class in the links.

*Stack Snippet*

```js
$('#buttons button').on('click', function() {
  $('#table-filters ul>li').removeClass('red');
  $('#table-filters ul>li[class="' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').addClass('red');
})
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}

li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  list-style: none;
}

p {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table-filters">
  <ul>
    <li class="link1">link 1</li>
    <li class="link2">link 2</li>
    <li class="link3">link 3</li>
    <li class="link4">link 4</li>
    <li class="link5">link 5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<p id="buttons">
  <button id="link1">link1 Button</button>
  <button id="link2">link2 Button</button>
  <button id="link3">link3 Button</button>
  <button id="link4">link4 Button</button>
  <button id="link5">link5 Button</button>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use `.each()` to iterate through nodes and dynamic selector to set the class for necessary element. Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kG2AZ/189/

And the snippet:

```js
$("button").each(function(i, item) {
  $(item).click(function() {
    $("#table-filters>ul>li.red").removeClass("red");
    $(".link"+(i+1)).addClass('red');
  });
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}

li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  list-style: none;
}

p {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table-filters">
  <ul>
    <li class="link1">link 1</li>
    <li class="link2">link 2</li>
    <li class="link3">link 3</li>
    <li class="link4">link 4</li>
    <li class="link5">link 5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<p id="buttons">
  <button id="link1">link1 Button</button>
  <button id="link2">link2 Button</button>
  <button id="link3">link3 Button</button>
  <button id="link4">link4 Button</button>
  <button id="link5">link5 Button</button>
</p>
```